# lapply with a split vector

Tags: r, lapply

I started off with the vector split_low

```
# Definition of split_low
pioneers <- c("GAUSS:1777", "BAYES:1702", "PASCAL:1623", "PEARSON:1857")
split <- strsplit(pioneers, split = ":")
split_low <- lapply(split, tolower)
```

Then I used lapply to select specific element from split_low vector:

```
select_el <- function(x, index) {
  x[index]
}


names <- lapply(split_low, select_el, 1)
years <- lapply(split_low, select_el, 2)
```

MY QUESTION is this: why does inputting `names` return a list of only the names (i.e. `"GAUSS", "BAYES"`, etc) and not the names together with the years (i.e. `"GAUSS 1777", "BAYES 1702"`, etc)?

After all, when I type in

```
split_low[1]
```

Or

```
select_el(split_low, 1]
```

R returns  `GAUSS 1777` rather than just `GAUSS`

How come lapply knows to separate the names from the years?

Comment: These R R's magick tricks that are not supposed to be known. After all, do you think it is by chance that R source code and help pages are SO HARD to read?

Answer (score 2):

To see what is going on, start by looking directly at `split_low`:

```
> split_low
[[1]]
[1] "gauss" "1777" 

[[2]]
[1] "bayes" "1702" 

[[3]]
[1] "pascal" "1623"  

[[4]]
[1] "pearson" "1857"
```

Notice that the result is a *list* of 4 elements, and each element is a *vector* of 2 elements.

When we type `split_low[1]`, this request the first element of `split_low` - which is the vector of two elements, `gauss` and `1777`.  (Technically, it is a *list* of length 1, containing this vector.  To get at just the vector, use `split_low[[1]]`.)  In contrast, when you call your `select_el` function, you apply a function to each element of the list, and that function returns the nth element of the corresponding vector - in this case, the first index returns names, and the second returns years.  Then, `lapply` creates a list out of these outputs - and hence the result of just names, or just years.

Comment: Amazing. I did what you said and you're right. I essentially misunderstood the fact that  `lapply` basically does the following: